# Портирование приложения с C на C++

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь портировать программу с C на C++. Делаю это первый раз. Достаточно ли просто переименовать файлы с `.c` на `.cpp`? По крайней мере, я попробовал, вот что вышло:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/craft.dir/src/db.cpp.o: неопределённая ссылка на символ «sqlite3_close»
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/craft.dir/build.make:469: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «craft»
make[2]: *** [craft] Ошибка 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «CMakeFiles/craft.dir/all»
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/craft.dir/all] Ошибка 2
Makefile:103: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «all»
make: *** [all] Ошибка 2
```

Что это обозначает? Ничего накопать не смог. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переименовать файлы -- обычно недостаточно (кстати, переименовывать их в общем-то необязательно, конечно, зависит от вашего makefile).

IMHO у Вас проблема с именем внешней функции. С++ в зависимости от типа возвращаемого функцией значения и ее аргументов добавляет символы к имени функции.

Вот пример (кусочек из вывода `nm`) для программы оттранслированной g++

```
0000000000400c32 t _ZL10ghtab_findP5ghtabPKvj
0000000000400955 t _ZL10ghtab_initjPFjPKvjEPFiS0_jS0_jE
0000000000400e93 t _ZL14ghtab_remove_eP5ghtabP7ghentry
0000000000400d89 t _ZL14ghtab_remove_kP5ghtabPKvj
0000000000400afb t _ZL14ghtab_traverseP5ghtabPFvS0_P7ghentryE
0000000000400cf2 t _ZL15ghtab_find_nextP5ghtabP7ghentry
```

а это соответствующий кусок для gcc

```
0000000000400c1f t ghtab_find
0000000000400ccf t ghtab_find_next
0000000000400951 t ghtab_init
0000000000400e50 t ghtab_remove_e
0000000000400d56 t ghtab_remove_k
0000000000400ae8 t ghtab_traverse
```

а это сами прототипы

```
static struct ghtab *ghtab_init (uint32_t capacity, 
                                ghtab_hash fhash, ghtab_cmpf fcmp);
static struct ghentry *ghtab_find (struct ghtab *htab, 
                                   const void *key, uint32_t keylen);
static struct ghentry *ghtab_find_next (struct ghtab *htab, 
                                        struct ghentry *preventry);
static struct ghentry *ghtab_remove_k (struct ghtab *htab, 
                                       const void *key, uint32_t keylen);
static struct ghentry *ghtab_remove_e (struct ghtab *htab, 
                                       struct ghentry *entry);
```

Соответственно, когда ld ее ищет в библиотеке, он такого имени не находит.

Прототипы внешних функций, которые транслировались Си-компилятором надо описывать для крестов вот так

```
extern "C" тип f(...);
```

Или можно всю пачку

```
#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
   ....

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif
```